# Two column table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, indexof

Considering the following code I would like to add a column on left with the text **"Player 1 :"** for each name (so first raw player 1,second raw player 2 and so on, I guess it can be done by `indexOf` maybe, but don't know how to use it...) but by adding the **array**

```
var player = [player];
```

I only managed to combine my names and 
my new array which shows me "undefined"

I'm quite desperate... 
Plus it output my first array in both columns... I do not understand how should I process...

As I'm a super new in Javascript please accept my appologies if my question may not sound so clear.

```js
function tableCreate(namesArray, Prénoms) {
  var body = document.body,
    tbl = document.createElement('table');
  var namesArray = ['Luke', 'Vador', 'Hann', 'Liela', 'Sith'];
  var playerArray = ["Player"];
  tbl.style.width = '7em';
  tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';
  tbl.style.borderCollapse = 'collapse';

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();
    for (var j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
      if (i == 2 && j == 3) {
        break;
      } else {
        var td = tr.insertCell();

        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(playerArray[j]));
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(namesArray[i]));

        td.style.border = '1px solid black';
        if (i == 2 && j == 3) {
          td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '6');
        }
      }
    }
  }
  body.appendChild(tbl);
}
tableCreate();
```

Comment: Well, `playerArray[j]` is always `undefined`, since `j` goes from `1` to `3`, but `playerArray` only has index `0`.

Comment: And you want to pass them but they are local vars too

Comment: @mplungjan but by changing j form 1 to 5 just add columns, I don't want to add colomuns, I just want to print Player with the index related to the name in my first column , and the name of my player in the seond column.